# Can Water Walking Boots in Terraria give fall damage?

Tags: terraria

In real life, if we fall from a great height onto water, we could break all our bones. In Terraria, I know that if you fall and land **into** water, you will be alright (as long as it's of a certain depth).

If I used the Water Walking Boots and landed **onto** water, would I be okay? Would it be normal fall damage? Or would I land on top of the water without fall damage?

I'm asking this for hellevator purposes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will not take any fall damage when landing on water/honey with the Water Walking Boots equipped.